# A given arboresescence is a shortest path tree if and only if $ d_B(r,v) \leq d_B(r,u) + l(u,v)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> **Definition** Let $D = (V, A)$ be a directed graph, with $r \in V$. Suppose that a directed path from $r$ to $v$
>   exists, for every $v \in V \setminus {r}$. An r-arborescence in D is by definition a set of arcs $B \subseteq A$ such
>   that $(V, B)$ has a unique directed $r -v$ walk, for every $v \in V \setminus {r}$.

Suppose a length function l : $A \to \mathbb R $ has been given with the graph $D$.
 We also know that no directed circuits
of negative length exist in D. Now, a shortest path tree (SP tree) rooted at $r$ for $(D, l)$ is an
r-arborescence $B$ such that the unique $r–v$ path in $(V, B)$ is a shortest path (with respect
to l) in D.

> Show that a given r-arborescence B is an SP tree if and only if, for every $(u, v) \in A$,
>   $$d_B(r, v) \leq d_B(r, u) + l(u, v)$$
>   where $d_B(x, y)$ denotes the distance in the graph (V, B) with respect to the length function
>   $l$ restricted to $B \subseteq A$.
>
> ---

**My approach:** $(\implies)$ 
We know that if we have an $SP$ tree rooted at $r$, we know that there is a shortest path from $r$ to $v$, because this is a shortest path tree, denote the distance $d_B(r,v)$. If we take any other point $u$ adjacent to $v$ on the shortest path tree we know that the $r-u$ path is also of minimal length. If we are at $u$ we still need to go from $u$ to $v$ now by some arc, this is given by the length function $l(u,v)$, in total we have travelled $d(r,u)+l(u,v)$. We are not certain this way of reaching $v$ will give us a path of minimal distance, but we know lengths are positive, so adding it will give us an inequality:

$$ d_B(r,v) \leq d_B(r,u) + l(u,v)$$
$(\impliedby)$ 
Now I am not sure how this inequality implies that $B$ is a shortest path tree.

I was thinking of negating the statement and generating some counterexample of the form: 
Suppose we have a tree that is not a shortest path tree, then there exists an arc  $(u,v)$ such that:
$$d_B(r,v) > d_B(r,u) +l(u,v) $$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Run the [Bellman–Ford_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) over the whole graph $(V, A)$ initialized as implied by $B$ (i.e., the `distance` and `predecessor` arrays calculated from $B$).
- Will there be any changes done by the algorithm?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$